# needed explanation for a c-program

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

In a c-book I bought, an exercise program is given as

> what is the output for the following code snippet?

```
printf(3+"Welcome"+2);
```

the answer I got is me (by executing it in TC++)

But I can't get the actual mechanism.
please explain me the actual mechanism behind it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called pointer arithmetic: 2+3=5, and "me" is the rest of the string starting at offset 5.

PS: throw away that book.

Answer (score 3):

When this is compiled the "Welcome" string becomes a `const char *`, pointing to the first character of the string. In C, with character strings (like any pointer), you can do pointer arithmetic. This means pointer + 5 points to 5 places beyond pointer.

Therefore ("Welcome" + 5) will point 5 characters past the "W", to the substring "me."

On a side note, as other have suggested, this doesn't sound like a good book.

Comment: On the contrary, I think its a good book, assuming it points out never to do this in real life. Such an exercise will help you grok pointers, arrays and strings in C.

Answer (score 2):

A string (like `"Welcome"`) is an array of characters terminated by the NUL-character (so it's actually `"Welcome\0"`).

What you are doing, is accessing the fifth character of it (3 + 2 = 5). This character is `'m'` (array indices start at 0).

`printf` will continue to read till it hits the NUL-character.